# Why doesn't "rm -i" work in a "while read" looping over the output of "find"?

Tags: bash

If I execute

```
find . -name \*\.txt | while read f; do /bin/rm -i "$f"; done
```

`rm` asks:

> /bin/rm: remove regular empty file ‘./some file name with spaces.txt’?

but the command exits without waiting for the answer. Why is that and how to fix it?

The other question on this subject, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398872/rm-ir-does-not-work-inside-a-loop loops through the `ls` output, but in my case `STDIN` is the  output of `find`, with multiple files, each potentially with spaces in them, so I can't switch to non-loop approach.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398872/rm-ir-does-not-work-inside-a-loop ?

Comment: @cnicutar Thanks. I updated the Q. I don't think I can switch to a non-STDIN based approach and just avoid the problem, like in the other Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping over the content produced by the default `-print` action of `find`, use `find`'s `-exec` action :

```
find . -name \*\.txt -exec rm -i -- {} +
```

In this command, `{}` represents the elements iterated over by `find`, and the `+` both delimits the command executed by `find -exec` and states that it should replace `{}` by as many elements it can at once (as an alternative you can use `\;` for the command to be executed once per element). `--` after `rm -i` makes sure the file listed by `find` won't be interpreted as `rm` options if they start by a dash but correctly as filenames.

Not only is this more concise (although not more easily understandable) , but it also avoids problems related to special characters naïve solutions would have.

Comment: I'd suggest `rm -i -- {} +` -- that way you pass more than one filename to each invocation of `rm` (and thus execute faster, since you aren't starting the program over and over needlessly), and don't choke on paths that start with dashes. (`-exec ... {} +` has been POSIX-standardized since 2008, so it's not relying on GNUisms).

Comment: (Granted, `find .` won't ever emit a path that starts with a dash, but sometimes folks run something like `find *.d -name ...` to let the shell expand a list of directories for `find` to start from).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree with the suggestion, I just need to find some time to rephrase my answer ;) OP, you should use `find . -name \*\.txt -exec rm -i -- {} +`

Comment: I tried it with and without `--` and they seemed to work

Comment: @MaxB the `--` makes `rm` interprets what follows as "not options", so if your `find` was to produce a `-f` file it would correctly delete that file instead of interpreting it as "oh, actually we're force-deleting, forget that `-i`!". As Charles Duffy points out, it can't actually happen with your current `find`, but it's still a good idea in case someone copies your `-exec` to another `find`

Answer (score 4):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' f <&3; do
  rm -i -- "$f"
done 3< <(find . -name '*.txt' -print0)
```

- **Put the content on a different file descriptor than the one `read -i` uses for input**. Here, we're using FD 3 (`3<` on the redirection, and `<&3` on the `read` alone).
- Clear IFS, or leading and trailing spaces in your filenames will be stripped.
- Pass `-r` to `read`, or literal backslashes in your filenames will be consumed by `read` rather than placed in the populated variable.
- Use NUL-delimited streams, or filenames containing newlines (yes, they can happen!) will break your code. To do so, use `-print0` on the `find` side, and `-d ''` on the `read` side.

Comment: I keep seeing this *a lot*. It just seems ridiculously overcomplicated when compared to Aaron's answer (which is what I would have written myself). Is there any good reason to prefer this construct?

Comment: @DevSolar, ...Aaron's answer is fine, it's just more limited -- you don't have a shell, so you can't maintain state between the items being processed. And if you're doing something *unlike* `rm` that would be a shell builtin in your loop, then `exec`ing code can be a lot of overhead. Bottom-line, what I'm teaching here is the more general practice.

Comment: I am not curious about any of the parts, I was curious about any real-world advantages it might have over the much simpler `find ... -exec`. Maintaining state it is, although it's not an advantage that applies to the question.

Comment: looks like this answer is more general (not just for `find`), but the other one was simpler for my use case, so I accepted that one. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Because `rm` inherits its standard input from the loop, which is connected to the output from the left side. So after `read f` got the name `foo`, there's nothing for `rm` to read from stdin. That's why `rm` exits on its own.

Don't use pipe if you need `rm -i` the prompt. There are many alternatives. One of them is

```
rm -i $(echo foo)
```

Comment: I must have updated the Q while you were typing the A. I don't think I can switch to a non-loop version (STDIN is the output of `find` with multiple files, each potentially with spaces in them)